# How can my app identify which social apps are present on user's iOS device?

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

We are building an app that is social in nature, and want to provide close integration to top social platforms like Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest etc. So I have two questions:
1. With UIActivityViewController, can we share content across all (top) social platforms available on the user's device? Or are there any known issues with compatibility for some of these platforms? I know Facebook has limitations in posting pre-filled text. But I couldn't find limitations for any other platform.
2. We want to see the list of all social platforms users are seeing, so that we can fine tune our app UX keeping that in mind. Essentially, we want to identify all the social apps a user has installed on his device. We want to detect presence of specific apps only and don't need all apps list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SLComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html) if your target iOS is >=6 and Social framework.

you can check for Facebook as:

```
     if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]){
```

and so forth for Twitter:

```
     if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
```

Keep in mind

```
  isAvailableForServiceType:
```

is the method used to return true or false in case user has setup/or no an account for the service questioned. And this method takes only one parameter for the service we need to know about (e.g. SLServiceTypeFacebook, SLServiceTypeTwitter). For [pinterest](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/) and some other social networks, you should use either their SDK or custom methods (basically all need to post url and content to specific url /servers).